# Implement transport security on my WCF service with custombinding on HTTP

Tags: wcf, soap, soa, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am new to WCF security . I am trying to implement transport security on my WCF service. We are using custombinding on HTTP. Can someone please suggest how can we do that?

`<customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000000"/>
        </binding>
</customBinding>`

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use Certificates to achieve transport-level security.

---

You can use this tutorial (below) on how to create "test" certs; for production I'd advise either issuing a cert using your own company's internal CA (if they have one) or use a trusted provider (Symantec, GlobalSign, etc).

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.110).aspx

---

You can use this tutorial (below) on how to install the certificate(s) on the box(es).

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb950259(v=bts.10).aspx

---

As far as the service app.config -- it should be *something* like the below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="YourServiceNameGoesHere" behaviorConfiguration="MyCustomBehavior">
      <endpoint address="YourAddressGoesHere" binding="customBinding" contract="YourIContractNameGoesHere" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomBinding"/>
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyCustomBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
          </clientCertificate>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="YourCertNameGoesHere" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
        <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" />                    
        <httpsTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

---

As far as the client app.config -- it should be *something* like the below:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="YourAddressGoesHere" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomBinding" behaviorConfiguration="MyCustomBehavior" contract="YourIContractNameGoesHere" name="YourClientNameGoesHere" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyCustomBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="YourCertNameGoesHere" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Zach , will I have to do any modifications on client configuration as well?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post and put what a client section might look like.

Comment: `customBinding` does not have a `mode` attribute for the `security` element... any ideas?